# Group child nodes based on the values of their siblings

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I've got this XML:

```
<RECORDS>
    <RETREC>
        <heading>Green Fruits</heading>
        <message>Kiwi</message>
    </RETREC>
    <RETREC>
        <heading>Green Fruits</heading>
        <message>Apple</message>
    </RETREC>
    <RETREC>
        <heading>Red Fruits</heading>
        <message>Apple</message>
    </RETREC>
    <RETREC>
        <heading>Red Fruits</heading>
        <message>Strawberry</message>
    </RETREC>
</RECORDS>
```

And I want to create a XSLT 1.0 template to get this HTML:

```
<table>
<tr><th>Green Fruits</th></tr>
<tr><td>Kiwi</td></tr>
<tr><td>Apple</td></tr>
<tr><th>Red Fruits</th></tr>
<tr><td>Apple</td></tr>
<tr><td>Strawberry</td></tr>
</table>
```

I've got this so far based on another Stack Overflow post but I haven't been able to find one where the original data matches this structure, and I don't understand it enough to know how to modify it to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:key name="heading" match="RECORDS" use="@heading" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <div>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(/RECORDS/RETREC)>=1">
                <body>
                <center>
                <table>        

                    <xsl:template match="RECORDS">

                            <xsl:apply-templates select="/RETREC/heading[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('heading',@heading)[1])]"/>

                    </xsl:template>

                    <xsl:template match="heading">

                            <xsl:for-each select="key('heading', @heading)">

                                <tr>
                                    <th align="center"><xsl:value-of select="heading" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></th>  
                                </tr>

                                <xsl:for-each select="RETREC">

                                    <tr>
                                    <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="message" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></td>  
                                    </tr>

                                </xsl:for-each>

                            </xsl:for-each>

                            <tr>
                                <td>&#xa0;</td> <!-- Adds a blank line in between heading -->
                            </tr>

                    </xsl:template>

                </table>
                </center>
                </body>
            </xsl:when>                 
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="/text()"/>
                <p id="No_return">No Records</p>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output you show can be generated simply by:

**XSlT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:key name="heading" match="RETREC" use="heading" />

<xsl:template match="/RECORDS">
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="RETREC[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('heading', heading)[1])]">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <xsl:value-of select="heading"/>
                </th>  
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('heading', heading)">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="message" />
                    </td>  
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```